# Is there an algorithm that can find steps to solve a set of equations

Tags: algorithm, path-finding

To start, I am not quite sure how to explain the problem and as a result have no clue how to search about it. It is as follows:

I have a large number of equations. The equations can be solved for any given variable, given the other unknowns, or can be solved simultaneously to solve for multiple unknowns. For example, given a and b, equations `f(x, y) = a` and `g(x, y) = b`, one can simultaneously solve to get x and y.

I need an algorithm that takes the known values and the equations and return the order in which solving them would result in the desired value.

Example equations:

- f(a, b) = 0
- f(b, c) = 0

Find c given a -> use eq1 to find b given a, then use eq2 to find c given b

Example 2:

- f(x, y, a) = 0
- f(x, y, b) = 0

Find x given a, b -> solve for x and y simultaneously using eq1 and eq2

I have attempted a simpler form of the problem using a graph, where the nodes are variables and edges are equations that connect them. However, this does not account for equations with more than 1 unknown and does not consider simultaneous solving.

Comment: What do you mean with the notation "a, b" ??? And how do you tell what is known and unknown ?

Comment: a, b are the variables that a certain equation handles, for example an equation y = f(x) would be marked as x, y. Order does not matter, the equation could also be given as y, x

Comment: Maybe use the implicit form `f(x,y)=0` for generality, then.

Comment: sure, will edit post

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of steps:

1. Match equations and variables as a standard bipartite matching; with edges between equations and variables (and if the maximum matching isn't perfect you have problems) https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/50410/perfect-matching-in-a-graph-and-complete-matching-in-bipartite-graph
2. Find minimal set of equations to solve simultaneously using strongly connected components
   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm
3. Those sets can then be solved in various ways; tearing is a common technique to reduce the size of the system even further; see e.g.,
   [https://people.inf.ethz.ch/~fcellier/Lect/MMPS/Refs/tearing.pdf](https://people.inf.ethz.ch/%7Efcellier/Lect/MMPS/Refs/tearing.pdf)

Comment: Hi, could you explain steps 1 and 2 further?

Comment: What is tearing ?

Comment: I'm afraid I still do not understand. The equations are not directional (f(x) = y can be solved for either x or y) so any nodes that are connected have to be strongly connected. This makes tarjan's algorithm redundant as it would simply return the entire graph.

The system seems to replicate my previous attempt, which was not able to solve equations which handled 3 + variables. Please help

Comment: That problem is solved by the matching. So in your example b is matched to f(a,b) and c is matched to f(b,c);